# How to cascade router LAN-to-WAN with NAT disabled? No internet access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, lan

[This Question is moved from Network Engineer StackExchange]

I have DPC3825 DOCSIS modem/router and an ASUS RT-N12+.

I would like to use RT-N12+ as my main Wi-Fi router so that I can use its features like QoS. The DPC3825 from ISP is too basic.

The problem with LAN-to-WAN is, if I need to access the devices connected wirelessly (DPC3825 to RT-N12+), I need to port forward them and I'm just too lazy to do all of that.

I wouldn't have to do that if I did LAN-to-LAN but then no QoS and whatnot.

If I disabled NAT on RT-N12+ and do LAN-to-WAN, there would be no internet access. I think I have read somewhere that I have to do static routing on DPC3825 for this method to work. DPC3825 is too basic that it does not even have static routing feature, so that's another problem.

My desktop is connected to the DPC3825. If only it was connected to the RT-N12+ also, I wouldn't have this problem at all since but it would be a hassle and I wouldn't go further why I can't do it physically.

Comment: *I have read somewhere that I have to do static routing on DPC3825 for this method to work.* You must set a (permanent) static route on each node in the segment between DPC3825 and ASUS RT-N12+ to the LAN subnet on ASUS RT-N12+ via its WAN address as a route gate. If DPC3825 (which is DHCP in that segment, is it?) have no this option  do it "by hands".

Comment: Did not get the "do it by hands" bit. How is that done? Is it done on client devices?

Comment: *How is that done?* It is performed by executing proper `route add` command on each node.

Comment: ah, I see. I guess with my current setup, this is not possible at all then. DPC3825 cant run commands AFAIK and it doesn't have static route feature on its web UI.

Comment: *DPC3825 cant run commands* `route add` must be executed on your PC, not on a router :)